# Bootstrap Modal disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Is their anyone with Bootstrap expertise who can solve my issue? I have modal loading dynamic data from MYsql db table. The problem is, It displays the modal disabled. Means i can't close it. I don't know how to solve it. Totally stucked.
Here is the complete code:

**Code**

```
<body>
<div id="popular" class="tab-pane counties-pane active animated fadeIn">
    <?php
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id ");
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'], 'http');
        ?>


        <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
            <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
                <div class="savings text-center">
                    <div>
                        <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
                        <div class="small">off</div>
                        <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end:Savings -->
            </div>
            <!-- end:Coupon data -->
            <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">

                <h4 class="coupon-title"><a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></a></h4>

                <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>">Shop these Shopname deals of the day  to save as much...</p>
                <p id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" class="collapse">Don't miss out on all the coupon savings.Get you coupon now and save big</p>

                <!-- end:Coupon details -->
            </div>
            <!-- end:Coupon cont -->
            <div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">

              <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal"  data-target=".couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">
                    <span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span>
                    <span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></p>

            </div>

            <!-- end: coupon wrap -->
            <!-- Modal-->
            <div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span> </button>
                        <div class="coupon_modal_content">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> <a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info"><span class="coupon_icon"><i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span>  <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end: Coupon modal content -->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--modal end-->

           </div>


        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <!-- jQuery  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <script src="owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Kupon js -->
    <script src="assets/js/kupon.js"></script>

</div>



</body>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

make sure the `z-index` of `.modal-backdrop` must be less than the `z-index` of `.modal-content`.

for example:

```
.modal-backdrop {z-index: 1050;}
.modal-content {z-index: 1060;}
```

Comment: So i just need to change `.couponModal` to `#couponModal`

Comment: I have checked and pointing to class rather than ID will have no effect on this issue.

Comment: @Gaurav i changed `<p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">` to  `<p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">`  AND `<div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  >`TO  `<div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal" id="couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  >` Still no change :/

Comment: @GauravPaliwal where can i fine this class??  `.modal-bootstrap ` it is not present in bootstrap.min.css

Comment: my mistake; it's `.modal-content` @tabia

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is css issue just you have to increase **z-index** of modal-content class.

```css
.modal-content{
  z-index:2000;
}
```

Comment: this will not work since by default .modal-backdrop (black transparent background) has grater z-index, 1040 i think!

Comment: This will not work either since `.modal-content` is a child of other elements that  already have z-index value. Please check my answer.

Comment: @krantikumar the problem is with  `modal-backdrop fade in` class. When i inspect element and remove this class it triggers the cancel button. But how to correct ot? Should i remove it?

Comment: @NightKn8 I also faced same issue.its works for me so just try it.

Comment: @NightKn8  Just remove **modal-backdrop** class. It will work. Because **modal-backdrop** class have opacity: 0.5 and position: fixed.

Comment: Adding this helped me .. Thankyou for your help `data-backdrop="false" data-dismiss="modal"`

Answer (score 0):

In your css try to add: `.modal{z-index:2000;}`
so it can be above `.modal-backdrop` that is transparent black.
If you are using own css file in document head place it under bootstrap css file, otherwise use `!important` in `z-index` but it is not recommended.

**EDIT:**
also make sure that you have the latest version available, this could also be the reason of something working improperly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did your working and yes the problem is `.modal-backdrop` but it still is showing backdrop class on whole screen when i inspect element

Comment: you have own css file? if yes put your  `stylesheet.css` under `bootstrap.min.css` and in your css file add: `.modal{z-index:9999;}`. Otherwise use `.modal{z-index:9999 !important;}` additionally for troubleshooting set `.modal-backdrop` z-index to 0;

Comment: no i don't have my own css. I am using it's library `bootstrap.min.css` and i have added z-index in it. But nothing happedned again :

Comment: i think my `bootstrap.min.css` file is not generating the changes. It says at the top `Generated sources should not be edited. The changes will be lost when sources are regenerated`

Comment: This also didn't worked for me! What's happening!! Is there any way to delete this node with class `.modal-dropback`? Because when i hide this node in Inspect element it works\

Comment: Add your own css file or `<style> </style>` below Bootstraps in your `<head>`, saying: .modal{z-index:9999;}